# Hogen.js - Load nested template with JS

Tags: javascript, templates, laravel-5, mustache, hogan.js

I got a postings template (Hogen.js) were I load data (api call from Laravel 5.3) into it.
I managed to load, compile and render the template and the data correctly.

Problem:
I have jquery/vanilla js scripts that need to work with the template and the data but somehow this JS is completely ignored by the rendered template and it doesn't work (onClick, other ajax calls etc.).

My load/render JS:

```
  var $page = 1;
var source   = $("#postTemplate").html();
var template = Hogan.compile(source);
$.ajax({
   url: '/api/postings',
   data: { page: $page} ,
   type: 'POST',
   success: function(data) {
        var output = template.render(data);
        $('.posts-container').prepend(output);
   }
});
```

My Template:

```
<script id="postTemplate" type="text/x-hogan-template">
        @{{#posts.data}} 
        <div class="post">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="@{{ imageURL }}" alt="post image" />
            </div>

            <div class="info">
                <div class="like-count" data-like-id="@{{ id }}">
                    more html
                </div>
            </div>
            @include('partials.comments')
        </div>
        @{{/posts.data}}
</script>
```

I include a partial from laravel with my "comment" code that needs to be execuded aswell (fadeIn, ajaxacalls,submit etc.)

Is it possible, that I cann ot execute my JS with the newly rendered template or DOM, because it's not available at document.ready?

Do I need to switch my template engine? Any other way to make this work?

JSON:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "posts": {
        "total": 46,
        "per_page": 20,
        "current_page": 3,
        "last_page": 3,
        "next_page_url": null,
        "prev_page_url": "http://localhost/api/postings?page=2",
        "from": 41,
        "to": 46,
        "data": {
            "40": {
                "id": 6,
                "name": " ",
                "imageURL": "",
                "city": "Spanien",
                "country": "",
                "created_at": "2018-03-11 09:40:25",
                "profilePictureURL": null,
                "social_src": 0,
                "mediumImageURL": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I stripped it down a bit!

Comment: can you post a sample of the JSON that is passed to the success function? That way I can give a more precise answer.

Comment: I stripped it down a bit!

Comment: but the thing is, that the initial first template is totally fine. The JS that I need is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use

```
   @include('partials.comments')
```

in your hgan.js template. Hogan is (almost) logicless. It is for binding JSON to HTML templates, it is not capable or intended for this use.

Partials can only be used like folows:

```
  var partialText = "normal text but can use {{foo}} is from a variable";
  var p = Hogan.compile(partialText);

  var text = "This template contains a partial ({{>partial}})."
  var t = Hogan.compile(text);

  var s = t.render({foo: chickens}, {partial: p});
  is(s, "This template contains a partial (normal text but we can use chickens. is a variable).", "partials work");
```

Basically {{>partial}} can be used to nest another precompiled template.

Comment: this is a laravel include tho.

Comment: I still don't believe you can do this as the Hogan.js templates are precompiled. You can read more about Hogan.js partials here using the hogan test suite https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js/blob/master/test/index.js

Comment: is hogan more for static sites?

Comment: No dynamic websites make good use of templating engines. Imagine you have a thread of comments on a forum. Each comment features the exact same piece of HTML markup, repeated. So we stick that in a template. Since we know what shape the data will be in, we can mark placeholders for properties. By making an AJAX call, we can retrieve the latest comments client-side, that can then be bound to the template and injected into the DOM.

Comment: If you read my answer, I think that's probably what you need to be doing. Create another Hogan template for comments and use {{>partial}} in the post template to include it